# Why does a MessageBox called via WinAPI give different errors on different computers?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-core

There is a nessesity to use WinAPI for my project. While I was studying WinAPI, I read about the method of getting errors Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().

I coped the example from the website [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netcore-3.1) and added  console project to .Net Core 5.0.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Win32
{
    // Use DllImportAttribute to inport the Win32 MessageBox
    // function.  Set the SetLastError flag to true to allow
    // the function to set the Win32 error.
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hwnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
}

class Program
{

    static void Run()
    {
        // Call the MessageBox with normal parameters.

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Win32 MessageBox without error...");

        Win32.MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Press OK...", "Press OK Dialog", 0);

        // Get the last error and display it.
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Console.WriteLine("The last Win32 Error was: " + error);

        // Call the MessageBox with an invalid window handle to
        // produce a Win32 error.

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Win32 MessageBox with error...");

        Win32.MessageBox(new IntPtr(123132), "Press OK...", "Press OK Dialog", 0);

        // Get the last error and display it.

        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Console.WriteLine("The last Win32 Error was: " + error);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }
}
// This code example displays the following to the console:
//
// Calling Win32 MessageBox without error...
// The last Win32 Error was: 0
// Calling Win32 MessageBox with error...
// The last Win32 Error was: 1400
```

The first computer that I tried worked well. 

After that I bought the new one and tried my project there.

The code began to work with the mistake: the error 1400 always came back after the calling messagebox, but the window showed and returned 1 (IDOK).

[image: Error with WinAPI]

**The first computer:**

- System manufacturer: MSI GF75 Thin 10UEK;
- Windows: Windows10 Home x64;
- Update: 20H2 (KB504237);
- BIOS: E17FSIMS.102
- Processor: Intel i7-10750H;

**The second computer:**

- System manufacturer: HP ProBook 440 G8;
- Windows: Windows10 Pro x64;
- Update: 20H2 (KB504237)
- BIOS: T70 Ver. 01.03.01
- Processor: Intel i7-1165G7

If I call GetLastWin32Error before the calling of messagebox, I'll get a error 0.

Has somebody got an experience like that? The problem is not very serious because of checking what  window returns. But I'd like to know what has happened.

Comment: What happens if you decorate your `Main()` method with `[STAThread]` ?

Comment: Are you sure you were running the exact same code? Seems impossible to reproduce. Sounds very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` calls [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

Calling `GetLastError` [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751139/11683) makes sense when the function in question returned a failed code. For `MessageBox`, [that is `0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox#return-value).

You call `GetLastWin32Error` regardless, so you cannot trust the value it returns.

To quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror#return-value):

> Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed. If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.

`MessageBox` is [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox#return-value) to set last error to 0 on success.

Comment: The Console.WriteLine calls before the MessageBox call does sets last error to 0.

Comment: @SimonMourier Then, in the process of calling `MessageBox`, the framework invokes some other API, e.g. `GetProcAddress`, which may or may not set the last error code. Then the `MessageBox` itself is invoked, which itself may call other API functions that may set the last error code - which could be because they genuinely failed and `MessageBox` handled the error, or because they pre-set the last error to an error code and then don't bother to clear it on success. And finally `MessageBox` returns success without bothering to clear the last error to zero.

Comment: Do some testing and you'll see